# LLVM Slower when pass activated

Tags: performance, llvm, libtomcrypt

I use LLVM to compile libtomcrypt, it's very fast (a few seconds) but when I use a blank pass (just a module pass that does nothing), it's very slow (several minute).

Someone know why?

I use Fedora 19.

The LLVM I use is LLVM 3.4 in release build.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about compile time or run time? And which passes are you running besides your blank pass?

Comment: I speak about the compile time. I didn't see any difference between the run time. I try some other pass too it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways in which an empty module pass can negatively impact compile-time:

#### 1. Pass Ordering

Module passes force a sort of synchronization point on a pass manager. So for example, let's say you have the following:

1. Function pass A
2. Function pass B

On a module with two functions `f()` and `g()`. The pass manager can (and will) first run A and B on `f()`, and only then A and B on `g()`. This is useful, among other reasons, for memory locality.
However, if you add a module pass:

1. Function pass A
2. Module pass
3. Function pass B

Then you force the pass manager to first run A on both functions, then the module pass, and then B on both functions.

#### 2. Invalidating Previous Results

From [the documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#specifying-interactions-between-passes):

> If a pass does not implement the *[getAnalysisUsage](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#writing-an-llvm-pass-getanalysisusage)* method, it defaults to not having any prerequisite passes, and invalidating **all** other passes.

So if your `runOnModule` method returns `true`, the pass manager considers *every* previous analysis pass as invalid, forcing rerunning them if they are needed later on.

For a more complete picture, I recommend reading the documentation for [a full explanation on what a pass manager does](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#writing-an-llvm-pass-passmanager).

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to see the documentation about getAnalysisUsage.